# Why is the noanswers tab (sometimes) in random order?

Tags: support, bug

I have been puzzling over why sometimes the unanswered tab is in newest-first order, but other times is not chronological at all. I cannot figure out this inconsistency or if it's something I am doing wrong. When I last noticed this, my address bar says:

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/python?tab=noanswers

versus when it is in newest-first, the address is:

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/python

Actually hmmm no- that is not consistently true either. This seems to be just an intermittent problem.

Comment: The unanswered tab is ordered by votes I think.

Comment: When it is not ordered newest-first, yes it appears to be ordered by votes. I will try to make a screen capture to show when it is differently ordered.